# Mysql Connect error: not showing anything at all

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working with `mysql_connect()` even though it's use is discouraged. My web service does not support `PDO`. I currently had my code formatted into `PDO` but now i have been forced to change it to `mysяl_connect()`. After these changes now I am receiving a page error and nothing displays. I am including a `database_connect.php` that is working with another page just not with my adapted code. What is the issue in my code that is causing this error? Here is my [PAGE](http://capstone.otiummusic.com/classes.php)

**Code**

```
include ('./snippets/db_connect.php');

      $query = ("SELECT  class_name, class_caption, class_credit_hours, class_description
                 FROM class                          
                 ");
      $query->execute();

     if ($query->execute()){

    $totalhours = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query )){  
        print "<b>" . $row['class_name'] . "</b><br>";
        print $row['class_caption'] . "<br>";
        print $row['class_description'] . "<br>";
        print $row ['class_credit_hours'] . "hrs. <br>";

        print "------------------------------<br />";
        $totalhours += $row['class_credit_hours']; 
    }

    print "<p>Total hours for Major: " . $totalhours . ".</p>";

    "<div> </div>"
```

Comment: you should do something like `$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);` to establish connection and have your pdo object to work with

Comment: Are you trying to achive Mysqli query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$query` is jsut a string, so there is no `execute` method. You never call `mysql_query($query)`. so there is no result set.

```
$sql = "SELECT  class_name, class_caption, class_credit_hours, class_description FROM class"
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     /// do stuff
  }
}
```

Also if your host doesn't support PDO you should switch, even if you arent planning on using it. There is no excuse for them not to support it at this point in time, it was made standard in php 5.1, and your host should at least have php 5.2.17 available if not the current stable of 5.3.

Now, if you know PDO you might want to try [`Mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of `ext/mysql`. Its more like PDO and supports prepared statments and what not. Your host should at least have that. If they dont then double emphasis on changing hosting providers.

Comment: Not to mention that even if `$query->execute()` actually did anything you'd be calling it twice which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this:

```
$query = "SELECT  class_name, class_caption, class_credit_hours, class_description FROM class";
$query = mysql_query($query);
if (!$query) {
    die("There is an error: " . mysql_error());
}
//continue your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct code should be:

```
include ('./snippets/db_connect.php');

      $query = ("SELECT  class_name, class_caption, class_credit_hours, class_description
                 FROM class                          
                 ");
      //execute query
      $result = mysql_query($query);

     if ($result){

    $totalhours = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )){  
        print "<b>" . $row['class_name'] . "</b><br>";
        print $row['class_caption'] . "<br>";
        print $row['class_description'] . "<br>";
        print $row ['class_credit_hours'] . "hrs. <br>";

        print "------------------------------<br />";
        $totalhours += $row['class_credit_hours']; 
    }

    print "<p>Total hours for Major: " . $totalhours . ".</p>";

    "<div> </div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand how you generated that code, but I think you are confused. It looks like you mixed in a couple different methods.  You are also calling execute() twice.  If you want to use PDO, I think you are trying to shoot for something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT  class_name, class_caption, class_credit_hours, class_description FROM class";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // Do you stuff with your $row
    }
}
```

If you are trying to use mysql_* (depreciated and unsanitized), I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT  class_name, class_caption, class_credit_hours, class_description FROM class";
$run = mysql_query($query);
if ($run) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array(run)){  
        // Do your stuff with your $row
    }
}
```